# Build Sync Failing when implementing SeekArc

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I'm trying to use SeekArc (https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc) for a project. However, when I try to sync my Gradle, I'm told that the build has failed. When I remove the line in my dependencies where I add SeekArc, the built is successful again. The full error message is below.

- I am adding jitbit as a repo.
- I've tried replacing `compile` with `implementation` or `api`

.

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\CommentsList\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-43 Error:
    Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-43
    is also present at [com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1] AndroidManifest.xml:36:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
:app:processDebugManifest

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

:app:processDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-43
    is also present at [com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1] AndroidManifest.xml:36:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
11 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 10 up-to-date
```

Not sure what to do, any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the [library's manifest](https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc/blob/master/SeekArc_library/AndroidManifest.xml#L33-L37) which contains an application node with

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
>
```

When is it time to merge your manifest and the library's manifest, there is a conflict with the icon argument. (Which icon should we use ?)

The solution is already given by the log.

Into you manifest file, add the tool namespace and specify the replace keep word. Replace will keep the attribute of your app's manifest.

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    >
   <application 
       tools:replace="android:icon"       
       ...
   />
<manifest/>
```

You will probably also run into the same problem with the label, and the replace will look like `tools:replace="android:icon,android:label"`

You can get more information [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) about the merge function.